How to Display a Square Image Scrolling Within a Widget with Half Its Height?
The title might be a bit unclear. I'm struggling to convey exactly what I'm aiming to achieve technically.
I want an app that, upon running, displays a square image within a SizedBox with half the image's height. Initially, the top part of the image should be visible, and then it should smoothly scroll down to reveal the bottom half.
I've tried solving this problem using ClipRect and AnimatedBuilder, but whether due to my misunderstanding of these widgets or because they might not be the right tools, I haven't been able to achieve the desired result.
To aid understanding, I’m attaching a video and the code representing my best attempt so far. :(
Here is the code and result I tried:
video : google drive
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ImageScrollAnimation(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageScrollAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageScrollAnimationState createState() => _ImageScrollAnimationState();
}

class _ImageScrollAnimationState extends State<ImageScrollAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  Size? _imageSize;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initData();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );

    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0.5).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      ),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initData() async {
    final image = Image.asset('assets/main.webp');
    _imageSize = await getImageSize(image);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (_imageSize == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    double adjustedHeight = getAdjustedHeight(_imageSize!, screenWidth);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, -_animation.value * adjustedHeight),
                child: child,
              );
            },
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/main.webp',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: screenWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 800, // 스크롤 이후 표시할 컨텐츠
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 800,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Size> getImageSize(Image image) async {
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();

  image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info.image);
    }),
  );

  final ui.Image img = await completer.future;
  return Size(img.width.toDouble(), img.height.toDouble());
}

double getAdjustedHeight(Size imageSize, double screenWidth) {
  double result = imageSize.height * (screenWidth / imageSize.width);

  print('Adjusted Height: $result');

  return result;
}


here you go buddy ;)
class DashboardPrev extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardPrevState createState() => _DashboardPrevState();
}

class _DashboardPrevState extends State<DashboardPrev>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    )..forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenWidth / 2,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return ClipRect(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0, _animationController.value * 2 - 1),
                heightFactor: 0.5,
                child: child,
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
             'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6yFzIYiRlIzc_Nb_KD3lmSmvtmJxr4eboXw&s',
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

